# Media player aborts automatically (player-status-change -> status = "aborted") for an unknow reason

Tags: agora.io

Integration was working perfectly for weeks but we now have a Media player status change happening without reason:

```
07:46:15:137 Agora-SDK [DEBUG]: Player 0 audio Status Changed Detected by Timer: init=>aborted
```

[Chrome console extract](https://docs.agora.io/en/Voice/autoplay_policy_web?platform=Web#handle-autoplay-policy-on-ios-safari-or-webview)

See below logs for more details:

```html
onmessage @ socket.js:40
EventTarget.dispatchEvent @ sockjs.js:170
(anonymous) @ sockjs.js:887
SockJS._transportMessage @ sockjs.js:885
EventEmitter.emit @ sockjs.js:86
WebSocketTransport.ws.onmessage @ sockjs.js:2961
wrapFn @ zone-evergreen.js:1191
invokeTask @ zone-evergreen.js:391
runTask @ zone-evergreen.js:168
invokeTask @ zone-evergreen.js:465
invokeTask @ zone-evergreen.js:1603
globalZoneAwareCallback @ zone-evergreen.js:1629
client:185 ./node_modules/pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'zlib' in 'C:\codeRep\aboard\node_modules\pdfjs-dist\build'
warnings @ client:185
onmessage @ socket.js:40
EventTarget.dispatchEvent @ sockjs.js:170
(anonymous) @ sockjs.js:887
SockJS._transportMessage @ sockjs.js:885
EventEmitter.emit @ sockjs.js:86
WebSocketTransport.ws.onmessage @ sockjs.js:2961
wrapFn @ zone-evergreen.js:1191
invokeTask @ zone-evergreen.js:391
runTask @ zone-evergreen.js:168
invokeTask @ zone-evergreen.js:465
invokeTask @ zone-evergreen.js:1603
globalZoneAwareCallback @ zone-evergreen.js:1629
meeting-board loaded
07:46:11:960 Agora-SDK [INFO]: Creating client, MODE: interop CODEC: vp8
07:46:11:962 Agora-SDK [INFO]: [23D44] Initializing AgoraRTC client, appId: 1790a8792d1e4ff9b1718dc756710f54.
07:46:11:963 Agora-SDK [INFO]: [23D44] Adding event handler on connection-state-change
07:46:11:965 Agora-SDK [INFO]: processId: process-79c97042-927c-45f6-83c0-48a79f7ecfbc
07:46:11:966 Agora-SDK [DEBUG]: Flush cached event reporting: 6
07:46:12:132 Agora-SDK [INFO]: [23D44] Added event handler on connection-state-change, network-quality
07:46:12:220 Agora-SDK [INFO]: [23D44] Adding event handler on connection-state-change
07:46:12:264 Agora-SDK [INFO]: [23D44] Added event handler on connection-state-change, network-quality
07:46:12:445 Agora-SDK [DEBUG]: Get UserAccount Successfully {uid: 10014, url: "https://sua-ap-web-1.agora.io/api/v1"}
07:46:12:445 Agora-SDK [DEBUG]: getUserAccount Success https://sua-ap-web-1.agora.io/api/v1 JXL5oSGFHauvWRdQVouA => 10014
07:46:12:453 Agora-SDK [DEBUG]: [23D44] Connect to choose_server: https://webrtc2-ap-web-1.agora.io/api/v1
07:46:12:469 Agora-SDK [DEBUG]: [23D44] Connect to choose_server: https://webrtc2-ap-web-2.agoraio.cn/api/v1
07:46:12:732 Agora-SDK [DEBUG]: [23D44] Get gateway address: (3) ["148-153-25-164.edge.agora.io:5886", "128-1-77-69.edge.agoraio.cn:5887", "128-1-78-92.edge.agora.io:5891"]
07:46:12:733 Agora-SDK [INFO]: [23D44] Joining channel: yqYjJu7a1slX8T9CxfNr
07:46:12:734 Agora-SDK [DEBUG]: [23D44] setParameter in distribution: {"event_uuid":"123"}
07:46:12:734 Agora-SDK [DEBUG]: [23D44] register client Channel yqYjJu7a1slX8T9CxfNr Uid 10014
07:46:12:735 Agora-SDK [DEBUG]: [23D44] start connect:148-153-25-164.edge.agora.io:5886
07:46:12:847 Agora-SDK [DEBUG]: [23D44] websockect opened: 148-153-25-164.edge.agora.io:5886
07:46:12:849 Agora-SDK [DEBUG]: [23D44] Connected to gateway server
07:46:12:850 Agora-SDK [DEBUG]: Turn config {mode: "auto", username: "test", credential: "111111", forceturn: false, url: "148-153-25-164.edge.agora.io", …}
07:46:12:930 Agora-SDK [INFO]: [23D44] Join channel yqYjJu7a1slX8T9CxfNr success, join with uid: JXL5oSGFHauvWRdQVouA.
07:46:12:932 Agora-SDK [DEBUG]: Create stream
07:46:12:936 Agora-SDK [DEBUG]: [JXL5oSGFHauvWRdQVouA] Requested access to local media
07:46:12:936 Agora-SDK [DEBUG]: GetUserMedia {"audio":{}}
07:46:12:937 Agora-SDK [INFO]: [23D44] Adding event handler on error
07:46:12:951 Agora-SDK [INFO]: [23D44] Added event handler on error, player-status-change, stream-added, stream-subscribed, stream-removed, peer-leave
07:46:13:132 Agora-SDK [DEBUG]: [JXL5oSGFHauvWRdQVouA] User has granted access to local media
accessAllowed
getUserMedia successfully
07:46:13:134 Agora-SDK [DEBUG]: [JXL5oSGFHauvWRdQVouA] play(). agora_local undefined
07:46:13:137 Agora-SDK [INFO]: [23D44] Publishing stream, uid JXL5oSGFHauvWRdQVouA
07:46:13:138 Agora-SDK [DEBUG]: [23D44] setClientRole to host
07:46:13:138 Agora-SDK [INFO]: [23D44] Adding event handler on stream-published
07:46:13:145 Agora-SDK [INFO]: [23D44] Added event handler on stream-published
07:46:13:172 Agora-SDK [DEBUG]: [23D44]Created webkitRTCPeerConnnection with config "{"iceServers":[{"url":"stun:webcs.agora.io:3478"},{"username":"test","credential":"111111","credentialType":"password","urls":"turn:148-153-25-164.edge.agora.io:5916?transport=udp"},{"username":"test","credential":"111111","credentialType":"password","urls":"turn:148-153-25-164.edge.agora.io:5916?transport=tcp"}],"sdpSemantics":"plan-b"}".
07:46:13:174 Agora-SDK [DEBUG]: [23D44] PeerConnection add stream : MediaStream {id: "SvvMFhU4Lx0jFjXTAK0DxYrmOLHyexu6dNKM", active: true, onaddtrack: null, onremovetrack: null, onactive: null, …}
07:46:13:190 Agora-SDK [DEBUG]: [23D44]srflx candidate : null relay candidate: null host candidate : a=candidate:2681806481 1 udp 2122262783 2a02:2788:2b4:58d:681b:8505:ebc2:9c35 50241 typ host generation 0 network-id 2 network-cost 10

07:46:13:197 Agora-SDK [DEBUG]: [23D44] SDP exchange in publish : send offer --   {messageType: "OFFER", sdp: "v=0
↵o=- 8826689166328964007 2 IN IP4 127.0.0.1
↵s…7242 label:9a3f62cf-5bd4-477a-b7b3-1fca64d6c2ca
↵", offererSessionId: 104, seq: 1, tiebreaker: 72973729}
07:46:13:218 Agora-SDK [INFO]: [23D44] Local stream published with uid JXL5oSGFHauvWRdQVouA
07:46:13:218 Agora-SDK [DEBUG]: [23D44] SDP exchange in publish : receive answer --   {answererSessionId: 106, messageType: "ANSWER", offererSessionId: 104, sdp: "v=0
↵o=- 0 0 IN IP4 127.0.0.1
↵s=AgoraGateway
↵t=0…bel:pa99gEbWHL
↵a=ssrc:44444 label:pa99gEbWHLa0
↵", seq: 1}
07:46:13:250 Agora-SDK [DEBUG]: [23D44] publish p2p connected:  Map(1) {3292 => {…}}
07:46:13:251 Agora-SDK [DEBUG]: Flush cached event reporting: 4
07:46:13:251 Agora-SDK [INFO]: [23D44] Publish success, uid: JXL5oSGFHauvWRdQVouA
Publish local stream successfully
07:46:15:137 Agora-SDK [DEBUG]: Player 0 audio Status Changed Detected by Timer: init=>aborted
07:46:15:138 Agora-SDK [DEBUG]: Media Player Status Change {type: "player-status-change", playerId: 0, mediaType: "audio", status: "aborted", reason: "timer", …}
07:46:15:168 Agora-SDK [DEBUG]: Media Player Status Change {type: "player-status-change", playerId: 0, mediaType: "video", status: "play", reason: "playing", …}
```

Anyone ever experienced this? Any hint?

Thanks

---

Received an answer from Agora:

Typically, this is because of the autoplay policy, you can find more information on how to bypass here:

[enter link description here](https://docs.agora.io/en/Voice/autoplay_policy_web?platform=Web#handle-autoplay-policy-on-ios-safari-or-webview)

I'll give it a try and update the post